# How to add brackets around footnote mark?

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to customize footnote mark in book class. I want it to look like the one below:
[image]
The command

`\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}`

works, however the brackets appear in the superscript. Then I edited .sty file by adding

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{(\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark})}}
```

but the result is still not what I expected. I need exactly regular brackets around uppercase index. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: I assume that the unexpected part is the fact that the footnote marker in the text also receives parentheses? This does not answer your question, but it would be better to place that line in your preamble (surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)) instead of modifying book.cls.

Comment: What is that does not work for your second approach?

Comment: The compiler seems to ignore the brackets in this command. The result is standard footnote, probably there is something missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{(\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark})}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{test}.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: intext sample]

in text, and

[image: foot sample]

in the footnote.  Is this the behaviour you want?